# Getting error when trying to use `CASE` in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, upsert

Good afternoon, I'm trying to run a query in PgAdmin to increment a value in my table if it exists, if not it will create the row, I'm getting an error however

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "CASE"
LINE 1: CASE 
        ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 1
```

```sql
CASE 
    WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM counter WHERE user_id = '321') THEN
        UPDATE counter
            SET counter = counter + 1
        WHERE user_id = '321'
    ELSE 
        INSERT INTO counter (user_id) VALUES ('321')  -- `counter` column is `SMALLINT DEFAULT 0`
END
```

I've also tried using the upsert

```sql
INSERT INTO cookies_counter (user_id) VALUES ('321')
ON CONFLICT (user_id) DO 
UPDATE SET counter = counter + 1
WHERE user_id = '321'
```

It gives me a different error instead

```sql
ERROR:  column reference "counter" is ambiguous
LINE 2: ON CONFLICT (user_id) DO UPDATE SET counter = counter + 1
                                                      ^
SQL state: 42702
Character: 100
```

Comment: In that context I think you'll want to use `if`, not `case`. I believe `case` is only used as an expression in another statement, such as within a `select` or `where` clause. See [here](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/plpgsql-if-else-statements/) for an example of the if statement

Comment: Also tried that, please see my edit @David784

Comment: SQL has no IF statement. You can only use that in PL/pgSQL which also supports a CASE _statement_ (SQL only has CASE _expressions_)

Comment: Alright, can you tell me how do I fix the error? Using standard SQL?

Comment: Non of these queries are valid SQL. It looks like some code from a pl/pgsql function/procedure, but not complete and thus not valid.

Comment: Juse use `insert ... on conflict` to do what is known as "UPSERT"

Comment: Use INSERT INTO.. ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE... : https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html

Comment: Please see my edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this might work, but it depends a little on the table structure:

```
CREATE  TABLE counter(user_id INT UNIQUE, counter smallint default 0);
INSERT INTO counter (user_id) 
VALUES ('321')
ON CONFLICT (user_id)
DO UPDATE
SET counter = counter.counter + 1::SMALLINT;
```

Comment: This kinda works, the only thing is that it doesn't add when `user_id` doesn't exist, it leaves it at 0. It should do -- if user_id doesn't exist - create user and `counter` should be 1, it if exists, simply add one to the current counter value. Thanks a lot for the answer though!

Comment: Use a default of 1 if 0 is not the default you're looking for.